# How to improve the digital recognition rate in fuzzy images

Tags: image-processing, character, image-recognition

I am currently working on some printed numbers on steel plates, using PaddleOCR, but some images are not clear, or the printed numbers themselves are not clear. How can I improve the digital recognition of such images.

e.g.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNHUD.jpg)

Please give me some suggestions, thank you in advance.

I wonder if we can use image preprocessing to make some changes to the image and then train it, but how to improve the recognition rate of the image that is not clearly printed.

thk ^^

Comment: Can you provide more details about your situation? How many images like the example do you need to work with? The example image you have provided is severely noised, and you will need significant amounts of preprocessing to even be legible to humans, let alone OCR. Depending on the situation, I could recommend just accepting these cases as a lost cause. But if most of your images look like this, I would recommend improvements to the image capturing system to begin with...